# Nginx proxy_pass doesn't send all of the request path to the server

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, networking, proxy

**The Environment:** 
I have a proxy server(nginx image) on port 80, an nginx server for backend on 81 and a backend(laravel) server on port 9000 all configured inside docker compose. 
 
**info:** 
In access.log file of nginx server I can see the url '/login' of 'GET' method is requested by proxy server but for some reason nginx server is only sending: '/' request to backend server. 
I also checked the full url in backend with this facade Request::fullUrl() and it returns 'http://backend'.
Also if I uncomment `# try_files $uri =404;` line in nginx.conf it only responses with 404. 
 
**Question**: 
How can I fix that?  
How can I send the whole url to my backend server? 
 
**docker-compose.yml file:**

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        container_name: thecliniclaravel_nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:rw
            - ./docker/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx:rw
        networks:
            - thecliniclaravel_bridge
        depends_on:
            - backend
    backend:
        container_name: thecliniclaravel_backend
        build:
            context: ./
        volumes:
            - thecliniclaravel_backend_vendor:/var/www/html/backend/vendor:rw
            - .:/var/www/html/backend:rw

            - ./docker/php/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:rw
            - ./docker/php/addon.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/addon.ini:rw
        networks:
            - thecliniclaravel_bridge
    frontend:
        container_name: thecliniclaravel_frontend
        build:
            context: ../thecliniclaravel_frontend
        volumes:
            - ../thecliniclaravel_frontend:/var/www/html/frontend:rw
        networks:
            - thecliniclaravel_bridge
volumes:
    thecliniclaravel_backend_vendor: {}
networks:
    thecliniclaravel_bridge:
        driver: bridge
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
upstream backend {
    server backend:9000;

    keepalive 8;
}

# upstream frontend {
#     server frontend:5000;
# }

index index.php;

server {
    listen 80;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    location /backend/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81/;
    }

    location /frontend/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:82/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 81;

    root /var/www/html/backend/public;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/backend_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/backend_access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass backend;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_keep_conn on;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
    }
}

server {
    listen 82;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/frontend_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/frontend_access.log;

    root /var/www/html/frontend/public;
    #.
    #.
    #.
}
```

Comment: why do your have 2 fronted servers on `80` and `81` ports?

Comment: bc i don't khnow how to configure them in one nginx server so it can send request to other servers in my docker-compose like the other frontend server.

Comment: proxy server can't find or resolve the backend for some reason, if i configure them in one nginx server

Comment: do you have some kind of firewall or something? Because you don't need your `proxy.conf` content, you can change directive `listen 81;` to `listen 80;` in `nginx.conf` and make necessary changes in `docker-compose.yml` to have single instance of frontend `nginx` listening `:80` port.

Comment: sorry my bad, i should have added the frontend server in my docker-compose.yml.   Essentially i want a proxy server thet derives request to the desired servers but i'm having difficulties to make the proxy server actually find the servers in docker-compose.yml

Comment: now nginx says this when i run `nginx -t`: " host not found in upstream "backend_server" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:52"

Comment: because you need to change to `fastcgi_pass backend;` to `fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;` in your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` line 52

Comment: @user973254 it fixed the config error but when i send request to 'localhost/backend/' my browser shows can't reach this page.

Comment: also it doesn't add any log to access.log when i refresh the page

Comment: @user973254 i updated again,        fortunately the host resolving problem is solved but still it doesn't send the complete url to backend when i request 'localhost/backend/login' , the backend shows `http://localhost:81` as the full url.

Comment: try to use IP addresses instead of confusing host names (which needs to be resolved first at least locally) or `upstream` names, so change `fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;` to `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` or if you returned to scheme using two `nginx` frontends `http://127.0.0.1:81`

Comment: hi @user973254, I'm afraid this is not going to do anything with my problem, even in backend_access.log file i can see the complete url is received, but fastcgi_pass directive is not passing it to back-end server, since i'm dumping the request full url from within backend server and it's just shows 'http://localhost'. :(

Answer (score 0):

Omg, finally, i forgot to put this in the backend server block in nginx.conf file: `include fastcgi_params;`
It's absence was causing my backend to miss other parts of the request except the 'http://localhost'.

(Sometimes i just want smash my head toward this wall beside me.
any way thank you @user973254 )